# Why does the edge of my Emission object have dark pixels?

Tags: rendering, materials, transparency

I am trying to render an object with a white Emission material in front of a transparent background, in Cycles and Blender 3.1.2.

When the object renders, the edge of the object has black or grey pixels:

[image]

And when I import it in After Effects for compositing, this is what it looks like:

[image]

I have looked for anti-aliasing solutions, but it seems things have changed in Blender 3.